# Old cartoon or anime featuring a girl protected by a Red Robot

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

I am trying to find an old cartoon, I remember it was about a young girl, possible a princess who was protected by a red robot on her journey.

I also remember that her father (I think) created two robots, one was red and one black, and he give them a test to see which one could protect his daughter.
The red robot was chosen, but the black one (I believe he was stronger) tries to stop the princess from getting where she is going. The black robot sends various robots after them but they are defeated by the red robot.

I can't remember any names, but I think that most of the action happens in a desert, there are not a lot of interactions in this cartoon, mostly the girl and the red robot traveling together and fighting other robots.

The girl might have been just the daughter of an important scientist (who created the two robots) and not a princes. She is young, probably a 10 years old.

Comment: What language was it in and where did you watch it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found a similar question [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130221232427AAmVlNo) where they say it is *[Zentrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zentrix)*, a 3D Chinese animated series, with an emperor scientist who has a daughter. The promotional poster also shows a black and red robot.

[image]

The relevant bits of the plot from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zentrix#Synopsis):

> Jarad takes precautions and develops two fighting robots - Zeus and
>   Quantum. Zeus is then chosen over Quantum as the protector of his
>   daughter, Princess Megan, should his mission in time fail. Following
>   this, Jarad and Roark head back in time.

It's from 2003, I don't know if that counts as old.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to add the poster and and relevant bits of the plot to your answer. You can always roll back if you are not ok with it

Comment: Thank you, I actually thought the question was describing something else, so investigated. I've never heard of this series but thought I might as well answer after finding it.

Comment: This is it, exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*[Robo Story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robo_Story)*

> Robo Story (sometimes referred to as Robostory) is a French cartoon series that was created by Michel Pillyser and Bernard Kessler for the French production company Belokapi and first televised in 1985.

....

> Robo Story follows the adventures of a small, orange-haired girl called Myrtille and her dog Loufi. In the opening title sequence we see Myrtille chase the mischievous Loufi onto a space shuttle that takes off with her inside. The ship crash lands on a world known as the Green Planet.
>
> The Green Planet is inhabited by robots. In the original French version these were the evil Rotors, and the friendly Robors. English language versions changed this slightly, renaming the evil robots the 'Wrigglers', and the friendly robots the 'Robos'.

### Opening sequence

Comment: Please do add more words. What is the plot of Robo Story? Why does it match? We already have an accepted answer, so for yours to have worth (which it might to other people looking for similar stories), we need you to explain why it could be the correct answer.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! The reason you "can't post unless you add more words" is because your answer needs to explain why you believe this show matches what the OP is looking for - you can't rely on the video to do that because there's no guarantee that the video will still be available tomorrow. Please edit your answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! As others have said please [edit] your answer to expand on how this matches the OPs story. It's also worth noting that this question has already been marked as accepted so there's a slim chance this is the correct answer.