# Anime with a blue robot protecting a young girl

Tags: story-identification, anime

I’m trying to find an anime I watched when I was a kid.

The main character is a young girl and has a blue robot protecting her. I don’t remember why he was protecting her, but I remember the blue robot fought a female or a male red one once in an episode.

I think the blue robot kinda looked like a robot from the movie chappie, only he had a mouth and could talk. The blue robot had a gun attached to his arm and a retractable sword in the other arm.

That’s all I can remember. It’s a good anime, I just can’t remember the name of it.

Comment: How many years ago you were "a kid"? The period when you watched this anime is an important clue, but at the moment it doesn't have any meaning for us. Also, if you could have a look at [this checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) maybe you could recollect some more details to [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/240994/edit) in the question.

Answer (score 6):

I just watched a series like this. It was called *[Brigadoon: Marin & Melan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brigadoon:_Marin_%26_Melan)*, I think. The character was a young female. She delivered newspapers and was an orphan, and then was protected by a blue robot and became friends with him.

> Marin Asagi is a typical junior high school girl with a loving adoptive family. Her life changes drastically when a mysterious mirage is seen in the sky above the entire Earth. The mirage is actually another world called Brigadoon. Soon, alien creatures called Monomakia descend from the formation in the sky and hunt down Marin, but she is saved by another Monomakia named Melan Blue, a flying, sword-wielding, gun-slinging alien who becomes her protector.
>
> Together, Marin and Melan must save the Earth and deal with family crises, school prejudice and the police, and come to an understanding of Marin's past and Melan's unexplained mission, as well as learn to trust each other.

Comment: This seems like a good match. The blue "robot" does protect a girl, and does fight a red "robot" in the first episode. Apparently, they're actually aliens rather than robots, but they look enough like robots that they could easily be mistaken for them at a glance. Also, the blue guy can definitely talk, and has a gun on one arm and a sword on the other.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you're thinking of *[Zentrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zentrix)*? It was the answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145259/old-cartoon-or-anime-featuring-a-girl-protected-by-a-red-robot). It involves a girl protected by a *red* robot against a *black* robot, but it was the answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150798/cartoon-yellow-robot-helps-princess-escape-from-coup-d%C3%A9tat?noredirect=1&lq=1) where the author admitted they got the colors confused, so I figure it's worth a try.

[image: Poster for Zentrix]

> The series is set in Zentrix City, a seemingly "perfect" city. Emperor Jarad is a respected scientist who created a super-computer called OmnicronPsy, which manages all of the city's higher and day-to-day functions, controlling a wide variety of machines and robots, allowing humankind to live a seemingly "perfect" life.
>
> However, OmnicronPsy, using its super-intelligence, decides that it would make a better ruler than Jarad, and breaks his coding that stops him from revolting. Discovering this, Jarad and the scientist Dr. Roark plan to head back in time 7 years to stop the revolt from ever happening. To do this they plan to shut down the six Zentrium chips that power OmnicronPsy. First however, Jarad takes precautions and develops two fighting robots - Zeus and Quantum. Zeus is then chosen over Quantum as the protector of his daughter, Princess Megan, should his mission in time fail. Following this, Jarad and Roark head back in time.
>
> Princess Megan notices the disappearance of her father, and upon entering his study, she discovers a message. Megan then tries to get the Time Machine working. At the same time, OmnicronPsy has cracked the code and sends two robot guards to kill her. They find her just as she activates the time machine and open fire - damaging the time machine and altering Megan's body to that of an eight-year-old.